# Two Object references point to each other

Tags: java

In objective C, there is a chance that two different references can point to each other.

**But is this possible in Java?** I mean, can two object references point to each other? If it's possible, when are they going to be garbage collected?

And, In case of nested classes, two objects (inner class's and outer class's) are linked to each other - how are these objects garbage collected?

Comment: An object reference can only point to an object. What do you mean by two object references pointing each other?

Comment: oh! I am new to java! In case of nested classes two objects(inner class's and outer class's) are linked to each other. If I make any sense here, how can these two get garbage collected

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*I assume you are talking about circular references .* Java's GC considers objects "garbage" if they aren't reachable through a chain starting at a GC root. Even though objects may point to each other to form a cycle, they're still eligible for GC if cut off from the root.

There are four kinds of GC roots in Java:

1. Local variables are kept alive by the stack of a thread. This is not a real object virtual reference and thus is not visible. For all intents and purposes, local variables are GC roots.
2. Active Java threads are always considered live objects and are therefore GC roots. This is especially important for thread local variables.
3. Static variables are referenced by their classes. This fact makes them de facto GC roots. Classes themselves can be garbage-collected, which would remove all referenced static variables. This is of special importance when we use application servers, OSGi containers or class loaders in general.
4. JNI References are Java objects that the native code has created as part of a JNI call. Objects thus created are treated specially because the JVM does not know if it is being referenced by the native code or not. Such objects represent a very special form of GC root.

You can also read [here](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/gc.html) for more information.

[image]

Comment: Does this mean a static initializer can run multiple times in a single class if the garbage collector collects the class and the program uses it in the future another time?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can do this. Like this:

```
class Pointy {
    public Pointy other;
}

Pointy one = new Pointy();
Pointy two = new Pointy();
one.other = two;
two.other = one;
```

They're garbage collected when both objects are not pointed at by anything other than one another, or other objects which are "unreachable" from current running code. The Java garbage collectors are ["tracing" garbage collectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Tracing_garbage_collectors), which means they can discover this sort of issue.

Conversely, [reference-counted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Reference_counting) systems (like Objective C without its "modern" garbage collection -- I don't know what the default is) cannot normally detect this sort of issue, so the objects can be leaked.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can have objects reference each other. You could simply pass the `this` pointer in both objects to each other, which is perfectly valid.

However, that doesn't mean that the objects are still accessible from the GC root. Think of it as a (graph) tree. If you cut off a complete branch from the trunk, the whole branch is lost, no matter how many objects are involved or are maintaing references to each other.